# Как можно на C# в Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word выровнять саму таблицу по центру

Tags: c#, ms-word

Пробовал всякими методами, не получается
Сначала создаю саму таблицу:

```
tb = doc.Tables.Add(doc.Paragraphs[10].Range, n + 4, 6);  
tb.Borders.Enable = 1;
```

Пытался по разному:

1)

```
doc.Range(doc.Tables[1].Range.Start,doc.Tables[1].Range.End).ParagraphFormat.Aligment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
```

2) `tb.Range.ParagraphFormat.Aligment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;`

Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Comment: А вы пробовали открыть Word руками и разместить таблицу по центру? Какие операции при этом использовали? Мне кажется что ваша задача в принципе некорректна, таблицу невозможно выровнять по центру, можно только с помощью линейки изменить размеры границ столбцов

Comment: Ну само собой руками легко и вполне возможно: 1)Наводишь курсор на таблицу; 2) Нажимаешь на пересечение стрелок в верхнем левом углу таблицы 3) Таблица вся выделяется; 4)Выравниваешь как надо(по центру,слева или справа)

Comment: Или иначе можно- переместить первый столбик таблицы. Исходя из этого,могу переиначить вопрос: Как переместить первый столбик таблицы

Comment: Когда выделяется вся таблица, то выравнивание сработает только для ее содержимого. А вообще стандартный подход: записать VBA-макрос для необходимых действий, затем посмотреть его код и перевести его на c#

Comment: Нет! Если нажать на кнопку в левом верхнем углу он работает с самой таблицей.А когда записывается макрос,эта кнопка,которая выравнивает таблицу становится недоступной! И даже если на нее нажать перед записью макроса,при выравнивании о делает это не самой таблицей а ее содержимым

Comment: Спасибо за совет,на счет записи макроса! Когда изменял положение первой линии(левой границы) VBA-макрос работал с app.Selection.Tables[1].Rows Позже я нашел app.Selection.Tables[1].Rows.Aligment  и приравнял его к WdRowAlignment.wdAlignRowCenter;  Раньше делала почти тоже самое,но только с колонками(типо первая колонка) пытался ее выровнять. А оказалось,что нужно работать со всеми строками таблицы

Comment: Так всё получилось у вас? Если так — напишите ответ с получившимся кодом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через пару дней разобрался сам:

```
app.Selection.Tables[1].Rows.Aligment = WdRowAlignment.wdAlignRowCenter;
```